# Regularization for Newtonian n-body collisions in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems

In working with binary collisions in the Hamiltonian formulation of the Newtonian $n$-body problem, two common regularization techniques that deal with binary collisions are the Levi-Civita technique, which regularizes collisions corresponding to terms of the form $\frac{m_1m_2}{q}$ (such as in a collinear setting, although this need not always be the case), and an adaptation by Aarseth and Zare which take care of terms of the form $\frac{m_1m_2}{\sqrt{q_1^2+q_2^2}}$ (such as in the planar case).

I wonder if there is an analogous regularization that would allow continuation of solution past terms of the form $\frac{m_1m_2}{\sqrt{q_1^2+q_2^2+q_3^2}}$ that would be encountered in working in $\mathbb{R}^3$?